# React map array inside serialized DRF with a manytomanyfield relation and StringRelatedField

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, serialization

From my Django DRF serializer, I'm trying to map an array with an object in React.
serializer.py

```
class AssessmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    objective = serializers.StringRelatedField(
        many=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'date_completed', 'objective']
```

The state from DRF looks ok:

```
{
  grades: {
    grades: [
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Quiz 4',
        date_completed: '2020-03-17',
        objective: [
          "kin.2",
          "kin.1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**But** I'm trying to separate out the kin.2 and kin.1 in my JSX table:

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.grades.map(grade => (
    <tr key={grade.id}>
      <td>{grade.id}</td>
      <td>{grade.name}</td>
      <td>{grade.date_completed}</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>{grade.objective}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Currently the 'kin.1' and 'kin.2' are printing on the same line with no space between the text.  I've also tried:

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.grades.map(grade => (
    <tr key={grade.id}>
      <td>{grade.id}</td>
      <td>{grade.name}</td>
      <td>{grade.date_completed}</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          {grade.objective.map(obj => (
            <li>{obj.objective}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

This comes close, the list is empty although it iterates the correct number of times.  Do I have to serialize some type of index with the 'objective'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grade.objective` is a list, so `obj.objective` wont work. Instead use `obj`

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.grades.map(grade => (
    <tr key={grade.id}>
      <td>{grade.id}</td>
      <td>{grade.name}</td>
      <td>{grade.date_completed}</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          {grade.objective.map(obj => (
            <li>{obj}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```